# I encrypted the data in the JNI code, but a lot of memory is generated and it cannot be released. What should I do?

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I have a question. I want to be able to encrypt my strings in JNI, using XOR + Base64 encoding. However, I found that some of the generated native memory was not released, and I didn't know where the problem appeared.

the memory profile is as follows:
[image]
[image]

I call 500,000 times in a loop so that I can observe enough information.

My Java code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    TextView tv = findViewById(R.id.sample_text);

    tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String source = "{\"page\":1,\"rows\":10,\"ucode\":\"150097\"}";

            for (int i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
                String encryptStr = CCLibrary.encrypt(source);
                String decryptStr = CCLibrary.decrypt(encryptStr);
            }
            Log.e(TAG, "completed.");
        }
    });
}
```

My JNI code is as follows:

```
Java_org_pp_va_android_jniprotectedbackup_CCLibrary_decrypt(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                            jstring str) {
    const char *rawData = env->GetStringUTFChars(str, nullptr);
    int stringLength = env->GetStringUTFLength(str);
    int resultLength = stringLength / 4 * 3;
    if (rawData[stringLength - 1] == '=') {
        resultLength -= 1;
        if (rawData[stringLength - 2] == '=') {
            resultLength -= 1;
        }
    }

    char *chars = nullptr;
    chars = new char[resultLength + 1];
    memset(chars, 0, resultLength + 1);
    chars[resultLength] = 0;

    unsigned long outlen = resultLength;
    int result = base64_decode((unsigned char *) rawData, stringLength, (unsigned char *) chars,
                               &outlen);
    if (result != 0) {
        memset(chars, -result, resultLength);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < outlen; ++i) {
        chars[i] = (chars[i] ^ XOR_API);
    }

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, rawData);
    return env->NewStringUTF(chars);
}


JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_org_pp_va_android_jniprotectedbackup_CCLibrary_encrypt(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz,
                                                            jstring str) {
    jsize len = env->GetStringUTFLength(str);
    char *c_msg = nullptr;
    c_msg = (char *) env->GetStringUTFChars(str, nullptr);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        c_msg[i] = (c_msg[i] ^ XOR_API);
    }

    char *c_encoded = nullptr;

    c_encoded = base64_encode(c_msg, len);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(str, (const char *) c_msg);

    return env->NewStringUTF(c_encoded);
}
```

I'm not sure where the code is wrong, maybe new char [resultLength + 1] or env-> NewStringUTF ()?

Can you help me?

Comment: I dont see where you delete `chars` and `c_encoded`? Thats prolly the mem leak...

Comment: You are right. Can I call  free(chars) and free(c_encoded) to release memory? Is there any other method that can be called?

Comment: No, `char` was allocated with `new`, thus you should use `delete []`. `c_encoded` gets allocated in `base64_encode` - you have to lookup its allocator and the corresponding deallocator.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. ```c_encoded``` uses ```malloc``` to allocate memory. I released it with ```free```. And released ```chars``` with ```delete[]```.